# Why isn't my footer sticking to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, footer

I need help sticking the footer to the very bottom of the page.

I have spent far too long trying to make my footer stick to the bottom of my webpage. There is so much online telling me how to do it but none of it worked. I must be doing something very wrong. Anyway, here's the code. It's not much. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Jim Bob - Online Portfolio
    </title>
    <!--CSS file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <!--Fonts-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="titleScreen">
            <table id="titleTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1 id="title1">Jim Bob</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1 id="title2"><span>ONLINE PORTFOLIO</span></h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <img id="downArrow" src="downArrow.png">
        </div>
        <div id="MyWorkDiv">
            <h3 id="myWorkTitle">My Work</h3>
            <hr>
            <img id="todayLogo" src="logoIcon.png">
            <table id="todayTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suo genere perveniant ad extremum; Atque ab his initiis profecti omnium virtutum et originem et progressionem persecuti sunt. Tu vero, inquam, ducas licet, si sequetur; Haec para/doca illi, nos admirabilia dicamus. Qua igitur re ab deo vincitur, si aeternitate non vincitur? Duo Reges: constructio interrete. In quibus doctissimi illi veteres inesse quiddam caeleste et divinum putaverunt. Tuo vero id quidem, inquam, arbitratu. Ille enim occurrentia nescio quae comminiscebatur; Hoc non est positum in nostra actione.</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img id="todayImg" src="todayApp.png">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr id="workBottomLine">
        </div>


        <div id="push">YOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</div>

    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <h3 id="contactMe">Contact Me</h3>
        <hr id="footerHr">
        <table id="contactTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img id="emailImg" src="@.png">
                </td>
                <td id="myEmailTd" colspan="6">
                    <p id="myEmail">jimbob@gmail.com</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img id="phoneImg" src="phone.png">
                </td>
                <td colspan="6">
                    <p id="myNumber" rowspan="6">my number here</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="icons">
                <td>
                    <img id="githubImg" src="github.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img id="linkedinImg" src="linkedin.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img id="dribbleImg" src="dribbble.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img id="twitterImg" src="twitter.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img id="instaImg" src="insta.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img id="fbImg" src="fb.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img id="googleplusImg" src="googleplus.png">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("alps.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#titleTable {
    width: 60%;
    height: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -30%;
    /* half of width */

    margin-top: -15%;
    /* half of height */

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

#title1 {
    font-family: 'Lobster';
    font-size: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#title2 {
    z-index: -999;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 2em;
}

/****** Title Lines On Side ******/

#title2 span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#title2 span:before,
#title2 span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    border-top: 3px solid;
    top: 50%;
    width: 73%;
}

#title2 span:before {
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

#title2 span:after {
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

/****** END OF Title Lines On Side ******/

#downArrow {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -37.5px;
    /* half of width */

    margin-top: -37.5px%;
    /* half of height */

    top: 85%;
    left: 50%;
}

#myWorkDiv {
    background-color: #1E2C55;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
}

#myWorkTitle {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10;
}

hr {
    color: white;
    width: 92%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#todayLogo {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

#todayTable {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

td {
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30;
}

#contactMe {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#contactTable {
    align-content: center;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#contactTable {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}

#contactTable td {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#contactTable td p {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #1E2C55;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    /* This line and the next line are not necessary unless you need IE6 support */

    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -440px;
    /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

#footer,
#push {
    position: absolute;
    height: 440px;
    /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

Comment: Can you simplify? Why you want to have #push the same height as the footer? what is its purpose?

Answer (score 0):

to make elements sticky you need to use `position: fixed;` (instead `position: absolute;`):

```
#footer
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, now add bottom: 0; and it's perfect, maybe z-index too

Comment: This brings it to the bottom of the window, but I want it at the bottom of the entire webpage.

Comment: so use the default position (static), that way the footer will be "pushed down" by the length of the website...